# How to get one field over collection in mongoid/rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I have a model

```
class MyClass
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :a, type: String
  field :b, type: String
  field :c, type: String
end
```

So how to get all the `a`-s, `b`-s or `c`-s as a list/array from all objects in the MyClass collection? Does Rails/Ruby/Mongoid have any syntactic sugar for this?

I know, it is possible to do so:

```
all_a = []

MyClass.desc(:created_at).each do |my_object|
  all_a.push(my_object.a)
end
```

But I thought about:

```
MyClass.get(:fields => :a)
MyClass.get(:fields => :a,:b)
```

## Update:

I found something:

```
MyClass.create(a: "my_a_string")
MyClass.create(a: "my_another_a_string")
```

Now:

```
MyClass.only(:a)
```

should work, but instead I get:

```
 => #<Mongoid::Criteria
  selector: {}
  options:  {:fields=>{"a"=>1}}
  class:    MyClass
  embedded: false>
```

When `MyClass.only(:a).to_a`

```
 => [#<MyClass _id: 525f3b9e766465194b000000, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, a: "my_a_string", b: nil, c: nil>, #<MyClass _id: 525f4111766465194b180000, 
created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, a: "my_another_a_string", b: nil, c: nil>]
```

But I thought about:

```
["my_a_string", "my_another_a_string"]
```

or

```
[{a: "my_a_string"}, {a: "my_another_a_string"}]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`MyClass.only(:a)`, will return every other field as nil, and the selected fields with their values...

You can use `MyClass.pluck(:a)` instead.
But you can pass only one field.

If you want more than one field, you can do this:

```
MyClass.only(:a,:b).map {|obj| [obj.a,obj.b]}
```

Comment: `pluck()` now accepts multiple fields. mongoid version 4.0.2

Answer (score 4):

`MyClass.distinct(:a)` is also sometimes better than `pluck` since it'll only return distinct values, which is better for populating dropdowns and so on.